# Can I have multiple instances of the same UserControl in 1 app?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, mvvm, tabcontrol

I am creating a Text Editor Type app. I can have multiple editors open via tabs. In my first try, I used simple `TextBox`es to edit text. Everything worked ok. Then I created a `UserControl` encapsulating the text box + buttons to perform text manipulation eg. bold/italic etc. I found out that when I open different tabs, they all contain the same content. eg. In Tab1 i enter "hello world" that will appear in all tabs. There is "no separation" even though they are in different tabs

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:EditorTabViewModel}">
        <me:MarkdownEditor />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I then as a test, tried a textbox and the usercontrol together to see if I have the same problem.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:EditorTabViewModel}">
        <StackPanel>
            <me:MarkdownEditor Text="{Binding Content}" Height="360" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Content}" Height="360" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I then discovered a few strange things. With a new document, where content should be nothing, my `MarkdownEditor` had "System.Windows.Controls.Grid" in its text box as it a Grid was bound to the text. Text simple `TextBox` works as expected. Also I still had the same problem with all `UserControl`s in the app having the same content.

**The XAML for the `UserControl`**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MarkdownEditMVVM.Controls.MarkdownEditor.MarkdownEditor" ...>
    <Grid>
        <ToolBar Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Command="{x:Static local:Commands.PreviewCommand}">
                <Image Source="../../Images/16/zoom.png" />
            </Button>
            <!-- more buttons -->
        </ToolBar>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="txtEditor" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="{Binding Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

## Update

I discovered that this has something to do with the way I have usercontrols rendered in the tabs where tabs are bound to `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>`

Suppose I have a **`TabViewModel`** even just a empty class

```
public class TabViewModel {}
```

Then in my **Window**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    protected ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> _tabs;
    protected ICollectionView _tabsCollectionView;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        _tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>();
        _tabs.Add(new TabViewModel());
        _tabs.Add(new TabViewModel());
        _tabsCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_tabs);
    }

    public ICollectionView Tabs
    {
        get { return _tabsCollectionView; }            
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I have created a simple Visual Studio Project hosted @[mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/?61aydndajjj6o3n) illustrating this problem. I have a feeling it got something to do with the `TabViewModel`s or the Tab Data Templates

## Update 2

I further tested the user control problem by adding another tab control, this time without the `TabViewModel`

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="1">
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
        <TextBox />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
        <TextBox  />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

It all worked ok. update also posted to [mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/?mcf7960f84tpn28)

## Update 3

Made yet another finding. This time, I tested with a binding. things worked fine ...

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabTitle}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Update also posted @[mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/?zcszjzgux0xysdn)

## Update 4

Ok now I did a more complete set of tests

[image]

- Row 0, Column 0: `TextBox`, Tabs bound to `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>`. No Bindings for `TextBox`. Problem observed
- Row 0, Column 1: TextBox, Normal TabItems, Tabs not bound to `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>`. No Binding for `TextBox`. No problems
- Row 0, Column 2: TextBox, Tabs bound to `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>`. No Bindings for `TextBox`. No Problems
- Row 1, Column 0: `UserControl`, Tabs bound to `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>`. No Bindings for `UserControl`. Problem observed
- Row 1, Column 2: `UserControl`, Tabs bound to `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>`. Bindings for `UserControl`. Problem observed. Text bindings not working

Update @[mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/?8sheh265ah0875v)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Big Edit** in response to updates

I can get your mediafire example to work correctly by taking the following steps:

1. Remove the dependency property `Text` from your user control - you don't need it
2. Change your `ContentTemplate` on the `TabControl` to the below.  This causes the `UserControl.DataContext` property to be set to the tab item `DataContext`

   ```
    <DataTemplate>
         <local:UserControl1 />
    </DataTemplate>
   ```
3. Change your `UserControl` to the below.  This binds the `Text` property to the `UserControl.DataContext.Text` property.

   ```
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
   ```
4. Remove the line `this.DataContext = this` from the constructor of `UserControl1` - this will obviously replace the `DataContext` for the user control.

This caused the tabs to be correctly bound with the expected values in the sample app you uploaded

---

**Original Answer**

You can have multiple instances of a `UserControl` - that isn't your problem here.

The reason you are seeing the "System.Windows.Controls.Grid" text is because in your `UserControl` you are binding the `Text` property to `this.DataContext.Text` instead of `this.Text` - the property *of* your `UserControl`.

I think what you want to do is change the `TextBox` binding in your user control to:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="txtEditor" AcceptsReturn="True"
Text="{Binding Path=Text,
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type me:MarkDownEditor}}}" />
```

Note: this relies on the `me` namespace being set up to point to wherever your `MarkDownEditor` is located

Comment: hmm, I tried that and got a StackOverflow Exception. I still dont really get the data context problem ... maybe because I never used `RelativeSource` too

Comment: That was my mistake - I was binding to the property on the `TextBlock` instead of on the `MarkDownEditor` :s - Post edited to correct problem

Comment: hmm, this is strange I still get the same Grid problem ... I also tried creating a custom control, more barebones in a clean application, I didn't have such a problem ... must have done something wrong somewhere, have you got any advice on such problems? as I develop, I somehow introduce wierd bugs tho they work ok alone. ie. when I have only 1 user control it works fine. should I just rewrite everything, then copy and paste functionality one at a time?

Comment: Unfortunately, debugging behaviour in WPF apps is generally a bit tricky as you often can't set breakpoints.  If I am getting the kind of behaviour that you are, I would generally change the binding of the property to something as simple as possible (e.g. `{Binding}`) and see what value that generates, and then work from there.  You can also set up an `IValueConverter` on the `Binding` in which you can specify a breakpoint if you are really struggling...

Comment: See update, I don't think the problem is with the bindings, I removed all bindings and I still have the same problem.

Comment: @jiewmeng - I've updated my answer to reflect everything up to Update 4 in your edits

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the **Writer** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to implement a text processing application with multiple tab support by applying the MVVM pattern.